# Full screen toggle for jQuery video player does not assign class-name correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I am working on a JavaScript/jQuery video player. It has a bug whose cause I was unable to find.

The players has, among others, an enter/exit full-screen button (it can be seen at the bottom of the HTML snippet):

```js
(function($) {

  /* Helper functions */
  /* 1) full screen */
  function toggleFullScreen(elem) {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
      if (elem.requestFullScreen) {
        elem.requestFullScreen();
      } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
    } else {
      if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
    }
  }

  $('video').each(function() {
    var video = $(this)[0],
      videoContainer = video.closest('div'),
      $playToggleBtn = $(videoContainer).find('input[name="play-pause"]'),
      $progressBar = $(videoContainer).find('.progress-bar'),
      $progress = $(videoContainer).find('.progress'),
      $current_time = $(videoContainer).find('.current-time'),
      $durationDisplay = $(videoContainer).find('.duration'),
      $volumeSlider = $(videoContainer).find('.volume-slider'),
      $mute_toggle = $(videoContainer).find('.mute-toggle'),
      $muteBtn = $mute_toggle.find('input[type="checkbox"]'),
      $rate_display = $(videoContainer).find('.rate_display'),
      $fullScreenToggler = $(videoContainer).find('input[name="screen-toggler"]'),
      $playSpeed = $(videoContainer).find('.playback-rate ul li');

    $(document).bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
      var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
      var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';

      if (event === 'FullscreenOff') {
        $(videoContainer).removeClass('fullscreen');
        $fullScreenToggler.removeClass('exit');
      } else {
        $(videoContainer).addClass('fullscreen');
        $fullScreenToggler.addClass('exit');
      }
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video poster="posters/poster.jpg">
            <source src="videos/mymovie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
  <div class="controls-wrapper">
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="video-controls">
      <li><input type="button" name="play-pause" value="Play" class="play" /></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="previous">Previous</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="next">Next</a></li>
      <li class="mute-toggle unmuted"><input type="checkbox" name="mute" /></li>
      <li><input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" class="volume-slider" /></li>
      <li><span class="current-time"></span><span>/</span><span class="duration"></span></li>
      <li class="playback-rate">
        <span class="rate_display">Normal</span>
        <div class="piker">
          <ul class="dropdown-content" id="rate_selector">
            <li data-rate="0.5">0.5x</li>
            <li data-rate="0.75">0.75x</li>
            <li data-rate="1">Normal</li>
            <li data-rate="1.125">1.125x</li>
            <li data-rate="1.5">1.5x</li>
            <li data-rate="2">2x</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="fullscreen-container">
        <input type="button" name="screen-toggler" value="Fullscreen" class="toggle-fullscreen" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The problem:** If I have two videos (or more), even if I click the full-screen button of the first clip, the `fullscreen` class-name will be added to *all* the `video-container` elements on the page.

Why does that happen?

**UPDATE:**

Following Kaiido's answer I have resolved this issue using the following code.

```
$(document).on('fullscreenchange', evt => {
    if ($(document.fullscreenElement).is(videoContainer)) {
        $(document.fullscreenElement).addClass('fullscreen');
        $(videoContainer).removeClass('fullscreen');
        $fullScreenToggler.removeClass('exit');
    } else {
        $(videoContainer).removeClass('fullscreen');
        $fullScreenToggler.addClass('exit');
    }
});
```

The problem mentioned above was solved. Yet, I lost the ability to use the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key as full-screen exit.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have pushed the player in a **[Github repo](https://github.com/Ajax30/videoplayer)**.

Answer (score 3):

You are binding an event to the Document object as many times as you have <video> elements in your page.

Stacksnippets don't allow fullscreen but a mockup of what you are doing is:

```js
$('div').each(function(i, el) {
  $(document).on('click', e => console.log('clicked'));
  console.log('added click event on Document');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

So every time you will enter or exit the fullscreen mode, all these events will fire and will set the calss on each of the videos regardless it was the one from where the event originated.

You'd be better add a single event handler outside of the `each` iterator, where you'd do

```
$(document).on('fullscreenchange', evt => {
  if($(document.fullscreenElement).is('video')) {
    $(document.fullscreenElement).addClass('fullscreen');
  }
  else {
    $('video.fullscreen').removeClass('fullscreen');
  }
});
```

But actually all your thing with the fullscreen class is useless since there is already a [`:fullscreen` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) that is natively set by browsers.

Comment: I need to add the class `fullscreen` to the `<div class="video-container">` element, not the `video` or document.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir doesn't change much to the core of my answer... Also note that you should call requestFullscreen on that div, and thus still don't need your class.

Comment: Your solution worked, as I have written bellow (in my answer), but I _lost_ a feature: being able to use the [ESC] key as full-screen exit.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I somehow completely missed that last comment, sorry. What do you mean by you lost the ability to use [ESC] key? From which browser? Can you set up a [mcve]? For me it still works in both FF, Chrome and Safari: https://jsfiddle.net/zd64fn8h/ And even though I didn't tried in IE, that should work there too, with minimal tweaks.

Comment: I have two videos. Here is the **[full example](http://code-love.tk/demos/video/)**.

Comment: I won't have time to look thoroughly at it tonight, but first observation is that chrome and firefox don't react the same. Is FF behaviors the one you want (i.e having both video always visible in the screen?) Also, your problem in Chrome is that you are not add/removing the class correctly. For one in `fullscreenchange` you are doing `else {
    $(videoContainer).removeClass('fullscreen');` while my answer told you to do `$('video.fullscreen').removeClass('fullscreen');`, when I thought you were toggling on a <video>,

Comment: but since you do it on divs, you can just do `$('.fullscreen').removeClass('fullscreen');`. Because at this point, we don't who was the last fullscreenElement, and we don't need to know it anyway. But even better would be to just get rid of this js controlled class and use the system one, as shown in my fiddle and also explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the problem is that in the "fixed" version you are attaching a single listener of 'fullscreenchange' to the document. Then in the handler of that event, you are using elements defined in the videos-elements-loop:

`$(videoContainer).removeClass('fullscreen');
 $fullScreenToggler.removeClass('exit');`/

both videoContainer and fullScreenToggler won't work as you expect.

Comment: How would you do it?